# plpgsql: Function that checks whether user insert unique time scopes into table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a problem creating psql function which is called as a trigger before inserting or updating a row in a table: 'Performance' which holds music performances during specyfic music festival.

What I want to acomplish is that the function will check whether the new performance beg_date and end_date won't collide with existing performances. The limit is that only one performance can take place at one time in given music festival.

The structure of table 'Performance' looks like:

```
id
beg_date : timestamp
end_date : timestamp
artist_id
music_concert_id
```

And the Music_Festivals:

```
id
beg_date : timestamp
end_date : timestamp
name
```

My function looks like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_valid_performance_date() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $check_date$ 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * from wystep) THEN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wystep WHERE beg_date > NEW.beg_date AND beg_date < NEW.end_date AND id_music_festival = NEW.id_music_festival LIMIT 1) THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'exception 1';
        ELSIF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wystep WHERE beg_date < NEW.beg_date AND end_date > NEW.beg_date AND id_music_festival = NEW.id_music_festival LIMIT 1) THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'exception 2 ';
        ELSIF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wystep WHERE beg_date <= NEW.beg_date AND NEW.end_date <= end_date AND id_music_festival = NEW.id_music_festival LIMIT 1) THEN   
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'exception 3 ';
        END IF;   
    END IF;  

    RETURN NEW; 
END
$check_date$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_valid_performance
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON Performance
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_valid_performance_date();
```

But I get 'exception 3' even though I start with the empty table. What's wrong with this function?

Comment: Look at the new range type in 9.2 combined with an exclusion constraint as mentioned by Falmarri. http://www.depesz.com/2011/11/07/waiting-for-9-2-range-data-types/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do this without a custom psql trigger using [exclusion constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) and [btree_gist](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/btree-gist.html)

Here's another question that does most of what you want I think.

[Postgres date overlapping constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616099/postgres-date-overlapping-constraint)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. However I could also use SQL OVERLAPS operator which "yields true when two time periods (defined by their endpoints) overlap, false when they do not overlap"