# Enforcing loose constraint in postgres between multiple clients

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, race-condition

I have a table that have the following fields:

```
entry_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
site_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
uuid VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
session_start TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
session_end TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
user_ip VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
user_agent VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
```

Now, I have a lot of incoming requests that have tuples of data along the lines of `(site_id, uuid, timestamp, user_ip, user_agent)`.

My rule is that if there is an entry in the database that is less 3 hours old (session_end), then the incoming request updates the `session_end = timestamp`. If not, create a new entry (where `session_start = session_end = timestamp`).

The incoming requests are handled by multiple processes. So say 3-4 incoming requests hit my servers with the same data (different timestamps, but milisecond-scale) and are handled by 3 different processes - how do I avoid creating 3 different records (if they all check at the same time, see no records matching and each create a new one)? It's a matter of a race condition and I'm not sure how to enforce it.

A table lock seems like overkill, as this is a write-heavy table, but what alternatives do I have outside of a 3rd party lock mechanism?

Example:

```
Format:
(site_id, uuid, timestamp, user_ip, user_agent)

Incoming requests / data:
(1, 123, 2014-01-01T10:00:32, '123.123.123.123', 'Mozilla/Chrome')
(1, 123, 2014-01-01T10:00:33, '123.123.123.123', 'Mozilla/Chrome')
(1, 123, 2014-01-01T10:00:34, '123.123.123.123', 'Mozilla/Chrome')

Result tuple:
entry_id | site_id | uuid | session_start       | session_end         | user_ip | user_agent
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<auto>   |       1 |  123 | 2014-01-01T10:00:32 | 2014-01-01T10:00:34 | ...     | ...
```

Comment: What about a `UNIQUE` index and handling insert errors in the apps?

Comment: How would you do a UNIQUE-statement for a time period? (site_id, uuid, user_ip, user_agent) can be set unique together, but multiple rows are allowed as long as no two session_start/session_end timestamps are within 3 hours of each other.

Comment: It sounds like those timestamps are natural keys.

Comment: Added example to clarify my point

Comment: Version? `select version();`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgres date overlapping constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616099/postgres-date-overlapping-constraint)

Comment: @ChristianP Oh, in that case you can use the exclude constraint, in fact there's almost exactly the same question on SO already, you just need to modify the range part: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10616099/2115135

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `gist` exclusion constraint with a `timestamp range` type

```
create table request (
    entry_id bigserial primary key,
    site_id bigint not null,
    uuid varchar(256) not null,
    session_start timestamp not null,
    session_end timestamp not null,
    user_ip varchar(40) not null,
    user_agent varchar(256) not null,
    constraint session_overlap exclude using gist (
        site_id with =,
        uuid with =,
        user_ip with =,
        user_agent with =,
        tsrange(session_end, session_end + interval '3 hours', '[)') with &&
    )
);
```

Now that insert fails:

```
insert into request (site_id, uuid, session_start, session_end, user_ip, user_agent)
select site_id, uuid, ts::timestamp, ts::timestamp, user_id, user_agent
from (values
    (1, '123', '2014-01-01T10:00:32', '123.123.123.123', 'Mozilla/Chrome'),
    (1, '123', '2014-01-01T10:00:33', '123.123.123.123', 'Mozilla/Chrome'),
    (1, '123', '2014-01-01T10:00:34', '123.123.123.123', 'Mozilla/Chrome')
) s(site_id, uuid, ts, user_id, user_agent)
;
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "session_overlap"
DETAIL:  Key (site_id, uuid, user_ip, user_agent, tsrange(session_end, session_end + '03:00:00'::interval, '[)'::text))=(1, 123, 123.123.123.123, Mozilla/Chrome, ["2014-01-01 10:00:33","2014-01-01 13:00:33")) conflicts with existing key (site_id, uuid, user_ip, user_agent, tsrange(session_end, session_end + '03:00:00'::interval, '[)'::text))=(1, 123, 123.123.123.123, Mozilla/Chrome, ["2014-01-01 10:00:32","2014-01-01 13:00:32")).
```

You may need to install the `btree_gist` extension as superuser

```
create extension btree_gist;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/btree-gist.html

Comment: Good suggestion, but for ease of implementation and for easier change of constraints (say 3 to 5 hours) I will go with the advisory lock solution. I didn't know about exclude gist constraints, so thanks for teaching me that :)

Comment: @Christian: I don't understand. The first process locks and inserts. Then the other process waits until the lock is released and inserts an infringing tuple. Is not that what you want to avoid? What do you gain just waiting?

Comment: I do some other checks, so I'll basically hold the lock before the whole pipeline starts and then release it at the end, preventing any tuples from being inserted wrongly.

Corollary, what is faster - trying and having a constraint error or checking and then inserting?

Comment: @Christian: A constraint is good practice weather you check before inserting or not. As I understand from your question you are doing a "upsert" and will always check. In my opinion the oddity here is the lock not the constraint but again there should be a constraint weather you lock or not. In my long experience I never found a case where a lock was superior or useful compared to a very simple `try/catch` provision at the application side.

Answer (score 1):

Check out advisory [locks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS).

```
SELECT pg_advisory_lock(key);
// INSERT OR UPDATE...
SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(key);
```

Or using the nob-blocking version:

```
SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(key) INTO :acquired;
// if (acquired) then INSERT OR UPDATE...
SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(key);
```

Comment: Ah, this would allow me to only lock for a small subset of the requests at a time, this would be perfect!

Comment: @ChristianP. yes, you are flexible here as you can define your own key that can cover a many sets you want.

Comment: Exactly. I will probably just add the different fields together excluding the timestamp and lock on that (calculating a . The pattern is that the first 2-4 requests come in right after each other and then they space out making it less of an issue. Cheers!

Comment: @ChristianP. Just realised that the non-blocking `pg_try_advisory_lock` would be even a better fit.

Comment: I am running this inside a transaction and I do want it to block, so I'll be using the `pg_advisory_xact_lock`. But thanks for the heads up :)