# Postgresql Trigger Not Firing

Tags: postgresql

I have a function and a trigger as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $logupdate$ 
DECLARE
judge boolean;
BEGIN 
judge := EXECUTE ('SELECT starttime,endtime,NEW.starttime,NEW.endtime FROM reserves WHERE bid = NEW.bid AND startdate = NEW.startdate AND (starttime,endtime) overlaps(NEW.starttime,NEW.endtime) IS NULL'); 
IF judge = f THEN RETURN false; 
END IF;
RETURN NEW; 
END;
$logupdate$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER logupdate 
before UPDATE ON reserves 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update();
```

The trigger should detect if the new input has overlapping with previous time, for example if there is an old time in my table [11:00 - 13:00], and a new input is [12:00 - 14:00] then the trigger should fire at it and stop insertion.
However, it doesn't work in my computer, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger gets executed for every row. You don't need to query the tables. You already have access to the old and new rows.

```
CREATE FUNCTION update() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $logupdate$ 
BEGIN 
IF (NEW.starttime, NEW.endtime) OVERLAPS (OLD.starttime, OLD.endtime) THEN 
RETURN false; 
END IF;
RETURN NEW; 
END;
$logupdate$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, this is super inefficient. You should consider using an exclusion constraint http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-constraints.html

I'm pretty sure there's an exclusion constraint that will work with OVERLAPS

Comment: thx for advice, however I get the following 'ERROR:  record "old" is not assigned yet' Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Oh, sorry. OLD actually isn't defined since it's a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger. My mistake. If you're only looking to do this on updates, and only care if the update overlaps with the previous value, you might want to change it to an AFTER update and throw an exception if it fails. Otherwise I would really just use an exclusion constraint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616099/postgres-date-overlapping-constraint